# CR2008 page footer insert then delete issue

Tags: crystal-reports

Open a blank report in crystal 2008 and insert a new page footer section. Then delete said page footer section. When you look back in section expert the "print at bottom of page" is still greyed out yet now unchecked. This causes the report to only display the PF on the last page after the detail and report footer. Is there anyway to reset it? Has anyone ever encountered this before on any version of crystal?

Answer (score 0):

`Open a blank report in crystal 2008 and insert a new page footer section. Then delete said page footer section.`

Firstly I am confused on why to insert a new page footer section and then delete it. If you are  not intrested in a new page footer section then why are you inserting?

Page footer is displayed at the end of every page. If your report has only one page then you will see that page footer is displayed after the report footer, But if the report is spread across the multiple pages then you can see the page footer at the end of every page.

Comment: The reason i said to do that first is so you can see the problem first hand. I know that is what causes the problem. Im working on a report for a client and i couldnt figure out why it was gone. Until i opened a new report and inserted then deleted the page footer. Once done i cannot get the "print at bottom of page" to become checked again. I know fully how the page footer should function. Does this help you understand a little better?

Answer (score 0):

You could always try inserting a new page footer and suppressing the old one, hopefully it will default in to every page then.

Comment: after it's been deleted, the "print at bottom of page" never becomes checked again. No matter if i insert another one or not.